# Bash standard I/O

Tags: bash, shell

First of all I have only one day experience with bash so my question may be really easy for most of you. Here is my question : The 2 codes shown below make same job however, thanks to I/O ,in one of them I don't have to use the `echo` command. I don't understand why. Is there anyone who can help me ? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
# make_page ----- A script to produce an HTML file------

title="System information for"

cat <<- _EOF_
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>
        $title $HOSTNAME
        </TITLE>
        </HEAD>

    <BODY>
    <H1>$title $HOSTNAME</H1>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
_EOF_
```

**The second one where I should use echo :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# make_page - A script to produce an HTML file

echo "<HTML>"
echo "<HEAD>"
echo "  <TITLE>"
echo "  The title of your page"
echo "  </TITLE>"
echo "</HEAD>"
echo ""
echo "<BODY>"
echo "  Your page content goes here."
echo "</BODY>"
echo "</HTML>"
```

Comment: The first is a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first script uses `cat` (which, in this case, outputs everything it receives from input), and here doc `<<`. Here documents are way to give input to a command, as though it's recieved from a sort of temporary file.

Here is the reference from `man bash`

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line  containing  only  delimiter (with  no 
>   trailing  blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are
>   then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>        <<[-]word
>                here-document
>        delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
>   pathname expansion is  performed  on  word.   If  any characters  in
>   word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
>   and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If word is
>   unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion,  command  substitution,  and  arithmetic  expansion.   In
>   the latter case, the character sequence \ is ignored, and \
>   must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.
>
> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters
>   are stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing delimiter. 
>   This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a
>   natural fashion.

Answer (score 2):

If you give `cat` no file name (like in question), it will read from standard input. Code in the question redirects standard input with `<<-TAG` ... `TAG` syntax from a so called ["here document"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), which is written inside the script.

Then `cat` outputs what it reads to standard output, same as `echo`.

Note: that `-` in the here document syntax has special meaning of stripping leading tabs, allowing the "here document" to be indented. It could be left out and simply be `<<TAG` ... `TAG`.

Answer (score 1):

The cat alternative uses a here-doc. It essentially displays the content of an entire file (in this case a here-doc). If you had a file website.txt containing 
    
        
            
            $title $HOSTNAME

```
    <BODY>
    <H1>$title $HOSTNAME</H1>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

You could just run

cat website.txt

to achieve a similar effect. Also notice that echo would, if

## $title $HOSTNAME

was included, display the values of these variables (if set) whereas cat doesn't.